# Wordpress + WooCommerce Get Product Tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have list of products on my website, each of them has own tag. I'm trying to show this tag on checkout page. I wrote a code, but it shows all the tags of all my products, not only that what in the cart. 
Here's my code:

```
      global $woocommerce;
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
  foreach($items as $item => $values) {
      $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
      echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>';
      $price = wp_get_post_tags($values['product_id'] , '_tag_ids', true);
      echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";


              $terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
      $term_array = array();
      if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
              $term_array[] = $term->name;
          }

  }


      print_r($values['product_id']);

      print_r($term_array);

      if(in_array('black',$term_array)) {
       echo 'hello exists';
      } else { 
      echo 'not exists';
      }

  }
    }
```

So it's showing correct = "hello exist" But it's showing because it's pull all tags from all products. How can i get a tag by product id. I store my product id in `$values['product_id']`
I have tried `get_terms($values['product_id'], 'product_tag' );` But it didn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use `get_the_terms`, not `get_terms`

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
```

Comment: Thank you! `$terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_tag' );` worked for me :)

Comment: It is a great answer, just use get_the_ID() instead of the_ID() if you don't want the post id echoed :)

Comment: Thanks, @PavelPetrov you're right, I'll update my answer, silly mistake on my part.